# How to iterate in a mongoose queried object and add value inside it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, object, mongoose

I'm having a problem regarding iteration in a mongoose query.
This is a result from a mongoose query:

```
{ chips: 50 },
{ chips: 100 },
{ chips: 150 }
```

Question:
How do I iterate through the values 50,100,150 and double them?

The output should be 100,200,300 because of the x2.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to update the db or just in the result of query?

Comment: I want to update the db

Comment: How these values are stored in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out.

```
 colltionName.update(query, 
    {"$set":{ $mul: { chips:2 }}},
    {"multi": true}
    )
```